# Connect a slider to control zoom on qml Camera

Tags: qt, camera, qml, zooming

I am using Camera to take movies.
I want to use a slider to zooming video like zoom of google map.
I've found another [Question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32991233/how-to-scale-a-particular-point-in-a-video-in-qml#) but the proposed solution works for click whereas I would like to develop a solution for slider.
I wrote code that is not working correctly.
I have not found error, but video size will be very large, then I do not see video.
I try to set digitalZoom for camera but I have this error:
**The camera doesn't support zooming.** .I know my camera does not support "DigitalZoom" and "OpticalZoom". I want to find a way to zoom in on video taken from camera.
**[My camera is dino ccd.](https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1089/1350/products/4023XC_large.png?v=1460917620)**
Excuse me friends, I can not add comment, I have this error: "You must have 50 reputation to comment".

```
VideoOutput {
     id: viewfinder
     source: camera
     anchors.fill: parent
     focus : true                                
     transform: [
         Scale {
             id: zoomScale
         },
         Translate {
             id: zoomTranslate
         }
      ]

      //Keys.onLeftPressed: viewfinder.seek(viewfinder.position - 5000)
      //Keys.onRightPressed: viewfinder.seek(viewfinder.position + 5000)

      MouseArea {
           anchors.fill: parent
           acceptedButtons: Qt.AllButtons
           onClicked: {
              var zoomIn = mouse.button === Qt.LeftButton;
              zoomScale.origin.x = mouse.x;
              zoomScale.origin.y = mouse.y;
           }
      }

      Slider {
          id:zoomVideo
          orientation: Qt.Vertical
          minimumValue: 0
          maximumValue: 100
          stepSize: 10

          onValueChanged: {
              zoomScale.xScale = zoomVideo.value
              zoomScale.yScale = zoomVideo.value
          }
      }
  }
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: What does `not working correctly` mean? What error/unexpected behavior do you get?

Comment: What device are you using? Basically all cameras support digital zoom only optical zoom enabled mobile cameras are rare.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to implement a zoom-in/zoom-out functionality using slider just like a normal mobile camera app does, if yes then consider the below untested code snippet because currently I don't have a machine with Qt IDE installed, but it should help you to understand the concept.

```
 Camera {
        id: camera
        digitalZoom:zoomSlider.value
        //if opticalZoom is supported uncomment below line
        //opticalZoom:zoomSlider.value

        // rest of your settings
    }

VideoOutput {
     id: viewfinder
     source: camera
     anchors.fill: parent
     focus : true  

     }

    Slider {
          id:zoomSlider
          orientation: Qt.Vertical
          minimumValue: 0
          maximumValue: camera.maximumDigitalZoom //or camera.maximumOpticalZoom
          stepSize:camera.maximumDigitalZoom/10   // going through 10 steps
          value:1.0                               // initial zoom level
          anchors{
           left:parent.left
           leftMargin:5
           verticalCenter:parent.verticalCenter
          }
      }
```

and also I would like you to have a look at the official documentation for these types.[Slider](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-slider.html), [Camera](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtmultimedia-camera.html#maximumDigitalZoom-prop) . If you need further clarifications post comments below.